# Example of a singly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote this implementation of a singly linked list but I don't find my code enough simple and compact. Could you help me to simplify it?

**Includes**

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
```

**Structure of data elements**

```
template<typename T>
struct Link {
    T val;
    Link<T>* next;
};
```

**Class of singly linked list**

```
template<typename T>
class SLinkedList {

  public:

    //Default constructor
    SLinkedList(): first_(NULL), size_(0) {}

    //Copy constructor
    SLinkedList(const SLinkedList<T>& other) {
        if(other.first_) {
            first_ = new Link<T>();
            size_ = other.size_;
            Link<T>* index1 = first_;
            Link<T>* index2 = other.first_;
            index1->val = index2->val;

            while(index2->next) {
                index1->next = new Link<T>();
                index1 = index1->next;
                index2 = index2->next;
                index1->val = index2->val;
            }
        }
        else first_ = other.first_;
    }

    //Destructor
    ~SLinkedList() {
        clear();
    }

    //Index operator
    T& operator[](int i) {
        if(first_) {     
            if(i < 0 || i+1 > size_)
                throw std::out_of_range("index out of range!!!");

            if(i == 0) return first_->val;

            Link<T>* index = first_;
            for(int it=0; it<i; it++) index = index->next;
            return index->val;
        }
        else throw std::out_of_range("empty list!!!");
    }

    //Access first element 
    T& front() {
        return first_->val;
    }

    //Access last element
    T& back() {
        return end()->val;
    }

    //Add an element at the begining
    void push_front(const T& value) {
        Link<T>* temp = new Link<T>();
        temp->val = value;
        temp->next = first_;
        first_ = temp;
        size_++;
    }

    //Add an element at the end
    void push_back(const T& value) {
        Link<T>* temp = new Link<T>();
        temp->val = value;
        temp->next = NULL;
        size_++;

        if(!first_) first_ = temp;
        else {
            Link<T>* last = end();
            last->next = temp;
        }
    }

    //Remove elements with specific value
    void remove(const T& value) {
        if(first_) {
            Link<T>* index = first_;
            Link<T>* temp = NULL;

            while(index && index->val == value) {
                index = index->next;
                delete first_;
                first_ = index;
                size_--;
            }

            while(index->next) {
                if(index->next->val == value) {
                    if(index->next->next) {
                        temp = index->next->next;
                        delete index->next;
                        index->next = temp;
                    }
                    else {
                        delete index->next;
                        index->next = NULL;
                    }
                    size_--;
                }
                else index = index->next;
            }
        }
    }

    //Delete first element
    void pop_front() {
        if(first_) {
            Link<T>* first = first_->next;
            delete first_;
            first_ = first;
            size_--;
        }
    }

    //Delete last element
    void pop_back() {
        if(first_) {
            Link<T>* index1 = first_;
            Link<T>* index2 = NULL;
            while(index1->next) {
                index2 = index1;
                index1 = index1->next;
            }
            delete index1;
            index2->next = NULL;
            size_--;
        }
    }

    //Clear content
    void clear() {
        if(first_) {
            Link<T>* index = first_;
            Link<T>* temp = NULL;
            while(index) {
                temp = index;
                index = index->next;
                delete temp;
            }
            size_ = 0;
        }
    }

    //Return size
    int size() const {
        return size_;
    }

    //Invert content
    void reverse() {
        if(first_) {
            Link<T>* first = new Link<T>();
            Link<T>* temp = NULL;
            first->val = first_->val;

            Link<T>* index = first_;

            while(index->next) {
                index = index->next;
                temp = first;
                first = new Link<T>();
                first->val = index->val;
                first->next = temp;
            }
            clear();
            first_ = first;
        }
    }

    //Display elements on output standard
    void print() const {
        Link<T>* index = first_;
        std::cout << index->val;
        while(index->next) {
            index = index->next;
            std::cout << "; " << index->val ;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

  private:

    //Access last pointer of data element
    Link<T>* end() const {
        if(!first_) return first_;

        Link<T>* index = first_;

        while(index->next)
            index = index->next;
        return index;
    }

    //First pointer of data element
    Link<T>* first_;

    //Size of list
    int size_;

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using c++, you should probably be using `nullptr` rather than NULL.

You also have a few edge case bugs:

- `clear` doesn't reset `first_` after it has emptied the list (you're currently only calling clear in your code just before you reassign `first_` or destroy the class which is why you're probably getting away with it).
- `pop_back` doesn't reset `first_` if there's only one item in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Some advices that you should follow to avoid further bugs:

- You should verify preconditions, especially in the methods `front`, `back`, `pop_front`, `pop_back` and throw an `std::out_of_range` or a `std::logic_error` if the list is empty before the call.
- You should add the `operator=` method. The implicit generated one will generate segmentation faults since the list cells will be shared (and destroyed) by two different lists.
- You should add a method `verifyInvariant` (class invariant) that verifies that `size_` is the size of the chain starting from `first_`.

You also can improve the usage of your class with new methods like:

- You can add a `swap` method and a copy constructor with xvalue argument to avoid some copies that are not useful.

Inside your methods:

- You can use `auto` each time the name of the local variable implicitly gives its type.
- If you use `new Link<T>{}` instead of `new Link<T>()`, all fields of the cells will be 0-initialized, avoiding some undefined behaviors in case of missing code.
- Think that an exception could be launched on every function/method call, so avoid allocations far from their integration into the list (see `push_back`) to avoid memory leaks in case of exceptions. Also keep in mind that the class invariant should be preserved in case of exceptions.
- You could choose better names than `index1` and `index2` in the copy constructor. We don't know on which list they iterate.
- The method `reverse` should not allocate any cell.

Here are the main modifications of the previous remarks on your code. Hope it helps.

For copy, assignment methods:

```
//Copy constructor
SLinkedList(SLinkedList<T>&& other) { swap(other); }
SLinkedList(const SLinkedList<T>& other) { copy(other); }
SLinkedList& operator=(const SLinkedList<T>& other)
  {  if (this != &other)
         copy(other);
     return *this;
  }
SLinkedList& operator=(SLinkedList<T>&& other)
  {  swap(other);
     return *this;
  }
```

For access methods:

```
//Index operator
T& operator[](int i) {
    if(first_) {     
        if(i < 0 || i >= size_)
            throw std::out_of_range("index out of range!!!");
        // more evident to verify that i >=0 and i < size
        if(i == 0) return first_->val;

        auto* index = first_;
        for(int it=0; it<i; it++) index = index->next;
        return index->val;
    }
    else throw std::out_of_range("empty list!!!");
}

//Access first element 
T& front() {
    if (!first_) // verify preconditions
      throw std::logic_error("empty list");
    return first_->val;
}

//Access last element
T& back() {
    if (!first_) // verify preconditions
      throw std::logic_error("empty list");
    return end()->val;
}
```

For the insertion methods:

```
//Add an element at the begining
void push_front(const T& value) {
    Link<T>* temp = new Link<T>{};
    temp->val = value;
    temp->next = first_;
    first_ = temp;
    size_++;
}

//Add an element at the end
void push_back(const T& value) {
    Link<T>** insertionPoint = &first_;
    while (*insertionPoint)
        insertionPoint = &((*insertionPoint)->next);

    // allocate it at the last time: this avoids memory leaks
    // in case of exception in the end() method for example.
    Link<T>* temp = new Link<T>{};
    temp->val = value;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    (*insertionPoint) = temp;
    size_++;
}
```

For the remove methods:

```
//Delete first element
void pop_front() {
    if(first_) {
        Link<T>* first = first_->next;
        delete first_;
        first_ = first;
        size_--;
    }
    else
      throw std::logic_error("empty list");
}

//Delete last element
void pop_back() {
    if(first_) {
        Link<T>* index = first_;
        Link<T>* previousIndex = nullptr;
        while(index->next) {
            previousIndex = index;
            index = index->next;
        }
        if (first_ == index)
          first_ = index->next;
        delete index;
        previousIndex->next = nullptr;
        size_--;
    }
    else
      throw std::logic_error("empty list");
}
```

Two implementation for the reverse method:

```
void reverse() {
    if(first_ && first_->next) {
        // memory leaks in case of exceptions
        auto* previousIndex = nullptr;
        auto* index = first_;
        auto* nextIndex = index->next;
        do {
            index->next = previousIndex;
            previousIndex = index;
            index = nextIndex;
            nextIndex = index->next;
        } while (nextIndex);
        first_ = index;
    };
}
```

or more exception-safe

```
void reverse() {
    if(first_ && first_->next) {
        Link<T> temp;
        temp.swap(*this);
        do {
            auto* cell = temp.first_;
            temp.first_ = temp.first_.next;
            --temp.size;
            cell->next = first_;
            first_ = cell;
            ++size_;
        } while (temp.first_);
    };
}
```

Additional methods:

```
void swap(SLinkedList<T>& other) {
    auto* tempFirst = first_;
    auto* tempSize = size_;
    first_ = other.first_;
    size_ = other.size_;
    other.first_ = tempFirst;
    other.size_ = tempSize;
}

bool verifyInvariant() const {
    int remainingCells = size_;
    auto* index = first_;
    while (--remainingCells >= 0) {
        if (!index)
            return false;
        index = index->next;
    };
    return index == nullptr;
}

private:
void copy(const SLinkedList<T>& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        clear();
        if(other.first_) {
            first_ = new Link<T>();
            size_ = other.size_;
            auto* indexThis = first_; /* indexThis, indexOther instead of index1, index2 */
            auto* indexOther = other.first_;
            indexThis->val = indexOther->val;

            while(indexOther->next) {
                indexThis->next = new Link<T>{}; /* avoid accidental undefined behavior */
                indexThis = indexOther->next;
                indexOther = indexOther->next;
                indexThis->val = indexOther->val;
            }
        }
        else first_ = other.first_;
    }
}
```